# ASP.NET Core Web App as an Azure Service Bus Consumer/Receiver

Tags: azure, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, message-queue, azureservicebus

I'm new to Azure Service Bus and have just followed the MS guide at the link below, to get 2 .NET Core console apps running. One as a Sender and the other as the Receiver/Consumer.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-dotnet-get-started-with-queues

What I need now, is to figure out how to configure a .NET Core MVC Web Application, to receive messages from a queue.

Ultimately, what I want to end up with is 2 x .NET Core MVC Web Applications of which can both add messages to a queue, and both be able to receive messages off of a queue. One website might add a message to a queue for the other website, and upon that website picking that message up/consuming it, it might need to send a message back to the original website.

I'm OK with the 'adding to the queue' side of it within the web application (as this will occur when certain events take place by the user), but my confusion is with the receiver/consumer side. How do I configure a web application to (as instantly as possible) pick up any messages that arrive on a particular service bus queue to process?

Comment: Hi @marcusstarnes,
I wonder if you've solved this and how?
Why wouldn't just start listener on web app start and close listener on app stop?

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to take a look on the [eShopOnContainers - Microservices Architecture and Containers based Reference Application](https://github.com/dotnet-architecture/eShopOnContainers) GitHub project and start from there. They have implemented a little framework for that (see *Microsoft.eShopOnContainers.BuildingBlocks.EventBusServiceBus* inside the project).

This is how it looks like inside the [Catalog Service](https://github.com/dotnet-architecture/eShopOnContainers/blob/dev/src/Services/Catalog/Catalog.API/Startup.cs):

```
protected virtual void ConfigureEventBus(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    var eventBus = app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<IEventBus>();
    eventBus.Subscribe<OrderStatusChangedToAwaitingValidationIntegrationEvent, OrderStatusChangedToAwaitingValidationIntegrationEventHandler>();
    eventBus.Subscribe<OrderStatusChangedToPaidIntegrationEvent, OrderStatusChangedToPaidIntegrationEventHandler>();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this git project can give you an idea.

It has 2 web apps - one is producer, one is consumer. In consumer you will see where listener registered.

https://github.com/damienbod/AspNetCoreServiceBus